# Passing results back to main thread from a cancelled BackgroundWorker thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

How can I cancel a backgroundworker and pass back an error message. I know that you can use `DoWorkEventArgs e.Results` to pass back results to main thread but `e.Results` gets overwritten when I cancel the child thread. Example:

```
private MyProgram_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     e.Cancel = true;
     e.Result = "my error message";
     return;
}

private void MyProgram_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     if ((e.Cancelled == true))
     { 
            string ErrorMsg = (string)e.Result;   //exception happens here 

            ....
     }
     else
     { 
          // success code
     }
}
```

Is there another way to stop my child thread and send a string back to the main thread?

Comment: Why are you cancelling it? According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.runworkercompletedeventargs.result(v=vs.110).aspx), the `Result` property will throw a `InvalidOperationException` if you cancel the job. So why are you then doing it **and** expecting a *result*? Basically your question is reading like "The documentation says that when I do X, Y will happen. I'm doing X. Why is Y happening? How can I avoid Y from happening?". I would assume (naively) that the answer would be "Don't do X". So don't cancel the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your long-running process was canceled, it wouldn't really have a "result", as the process didn't completely finish.

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.runworkercompletedeventargs.result%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Your RunWorkerCompleted event handler should always check the Error and Cancelled properties before accessing the Result property. If an exception was raised or if the operation was canceled, accessing the Result property raises an exception.

I took a peek inside `BackgroundWorker`. Here's the contents of the `Result` property:

```
public object Result
{
  get
  {
    this.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary();
    return this.result;
  }
}
```

And the contents of `RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()`:

```
protected void RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
{
  if (this.Error != null)
    throw new TargetInvocationException(SR.GetString("Async_ExceptionOccurred"), this.Error);
  if (this.Cancelled)
    throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString("Async_OperationCancelled"));
}
```

So if you cancel the thread, referencing `Result` will throw an `InvalidOperationException`. That's just the way it's designed.

I don't know what the "best" way is to pass a string back. I'd say you could define a variable in the same method you run the BackgroundWorker from, and assign a value to it from the `DoWork` event.

You just have to be very careful that *nothing* on the UI thread is somehow bound to the variable or you could run into problems. A string should be safe, but don't start adding to a list that's bound to a ComboBox or something.